# Simple manual load balancing

Tags: windows, configuration, nic

We're running a Windows 2016 AD server (ATLB-SRV01.atlb.local) that includes two NICs.

We have assigned each NIC a different IP and give them a proper name in the DNS server (type A record).

Example:

NIC1 -> 128.127.100.1 -> DNS 'A' record: atlb-srv01.atlb.local

NIC2 -> 128.127.100.2 -> DNS 'A' record: atlb-srv01-2.atlb.local

AD installation was made using NIC1 and this is the only NIC with gateway assigned. Both NICs are in the same subnet and we can ping to any of them without any problem, either by name or by IP.

Then, we shared a folder in the server, say 'D:\Group2', that is available as '\ATLB-SRV01\Group2', but we want to be accessed by some client computers using '\ATLB-SRV01-2\Group2'.

When a client try to connect to the share using '\ATLB-SRV01-2\Group2', windows shows a security window requesting for user and password. No user and password is recognized as valid and is not possible to access the resource.

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to utilize multiple NICs on a machine for redundancy and/or link aggregation: use NIC teaming https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nic-teaming/nic-teaming

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gert. I've had a bad experience when teaming was not included at OS level and depends on manufacturer drivers. Have you tested native windows teaming with success?

Comment: Yes, I have experience with it. It works fine. Check compatibility of your NIC first.

Answer (score 1):

Trywith These Command

```
DNSCMD dc1.contoso.local /RecordAdd contoso.local File1 A 192.168.1.11
```

But It is not a recommended solution.(it can be used.)
You can use below methods

- Alternate Computer Names and Dynamic DNS
- DFS Consolidation Roots
- Virtual Machines
- Failover Clusters

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple NICs does not automatically multiply your machines names, which is the local security authority (and default CN on all your certificates). New names are "wrong" names by default; that is why you get those logon requests.

You will have to add multiple windows server names, like this:

```
NETDOM COMPUTERNAME atlb-srv01 /ADD atlb-srv01-2.atlb.local
```

followed by

```
IPCONFIG /registerdns
```

But I would *strongly* advise to use proper NIC teaming, as this is not really transparent and has sometimes strange side effects. Also teaming is possibly on the os level on almost any WHQL driven nic.

If you still want to go with manual-certain-nic-loadbalancing-stuff, think about your routing. Windows does not necessarly answer TCP connections on the "incoming" nic, but on the incoming route.

Comment: Thanks bjoster. This solves what I asked for initially. After trying native windows NIC teaming as Gert and you have suggested, I opted for this approach.